# Inferring absolute path from compilerOptions paths

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig-paths, tsconfig.json

I'm using [compilerOptions: paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) together with [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths)

```
$ cat tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": { "@folder1/*": ["utils/*"] },
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

Here is the simple example I use

```js
import 'tsconfig-paths/register';
import { myLovelyUtilsFunction } from "@folder1/myUtils"
const y = myLovelyUtilsFunction();
console.log(`>>> ${y}`);
```

Transpiling and running goes fine:

```bash
$ npx tsc -p tsconfig.json
$ node src/main.js        
### expected output ...
```

I want to *resolve the absolute path* locations at *transpilation* time, [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths):

> If you require this package's `tsconfig-paths/register` module it will read the paths from `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json` and *convert* node's module loading calls into to *physical file paths* that node can load

But when I look at the generated javascript file I see the load will be done on *runtime*:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
require("tsconfig-paths/register");
var myUtils_1 = require("@folder1/myUtils"); // <--- why not resolve it ?
var y = (0, myUtils_1.myLovelyUtilsFunction)();
console.log(">>> ".concat(y));
```